# What is the correct file extension I should use for a newly created PostgreSQL schema that I created?

Tags: database, postgresql, file

I have created a new schema for a new PostgreSQL DB that I want to create (IF NOT EXISTS).

What should the file extension be for this document so that I can run it from psql, .dbu or .sql?

Comment: `.sql` is the usual extension. No idea what `dbu` is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

.dbu is used as a "Database Utility" file

You need to use .sql

Then from psql you can use something like:

```
SET search_path = schemaName, something_else;
SELECT * FROM tableName;        -- schemaName.tableName
```

or something to that effect depending on what you're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

For the updated version of Postgres, you can name **.spsql** as the file extension.
then from vs if you are using vs you can download the needed extension and connect to the database.

Comment: "spsql"?! may be "pssql"?